# How would you write this using the composition api?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

```
  computed: {
    userName() {
      // (4) Display authenticated user name
      const user = this.$gapi.getUserData()

      return user.accessToken
    },
  },
```

This is the code im trying to convert to the Vue3 composition API. Essentially i understand i need to import computed and so on but the part i can't seem to work out is how to write `this.$gapi.getUserData()` in the setup function.

gapi is an imported package im using..

Answer (score 1):

Global properties are setup on [`app.config.globalProperties`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-config.html#globalproperties) in Vue 3, and the application instance can be retrieved via `getCurrentInstance().appContext`.

The equivalent Composition API would be similar to this:

```js
import { getCurrentInstance, computed } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const currentInstance = getCurrentInstance()
    return {
      userName: computed(() => {
        const user = currentInstance.appContext.config.globalProperties.$gapi.getUserData()
        return user.accessToken
      })
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-get-global-props-from-setup-hook?file=src/components/HelloWorld.vue)