# How can I refer to Vue 3 prototype?

Tags: vue.js

in Vue 2 I can assign a prototype in main.js for example via `Vue.prototype.$AppName` in Vue 3 I can assign a prototype to for example `app.config.globalProperties.appName` but how can I get the prototype value in a component. I can't use this.appName like in Vue 2 because of the proxy

Comment: Are you trying to access `appName` from within `setup()`? If so, see [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68060564/6277151).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add global variable in Vue.js 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63100658/add-global-variable-in-vue-js-3)